# assertJson is not equal to expected to actual in laravel

Tags: laravel, unit-testing

I'm new in unit tests in laravel and currently facing an error on my test. Please see my code below.

**Test**

```
/** @test */
public function users_can_view_homepage_products()
{
    $response = $this->get('api/products');
    
    $response->assertStatus(200)
        ->assertJson([
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => ucwords($this->faker->words(3, true)),
            'slug' => ucfirst($this->faker->slug),
            'intro' => $this->faker->sentence,
            'price' => number_format($this->faker->randomFloat(2, 100, 99999), 2)
        ]);
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    return [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Airpods Pro (2021)',
        'slug' => 'airpods-pro-2021',
        'intro' => 'New and powerful airpods from apple.',
        'price' => 12400
    ];
}
```

**Error**

[image]

Comment: test case failed with the price is not match with the test scenario please add and try only integer values in price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test fails because the content of the json is different to that being tested. You probably want to test that the structure is the same, rather than the content:

```
/** @test */
public function users_can_view_homepage_products()
{
    $response = $this->get('api/products');
    
    $response->assertStatus(200)
        ->assertJsonStructure([
            'id',
            'name'
            'slug'
            'intro'
            'price'
        ]);
}
```